# Does Jenkins/Hudson require maven-surefire-plugin to publish test results?

Tags: maven, jenkins, hudson, maven-surefire-plugin

Does Jenkins/Hudson require maven-surefire-plugin to be executed in order to display "Latest Test Result", "Test Result Trend" diagram and to allow users to drill down to specific classes/tests? I was under impression it is necessary to run Surefire, but it seems that in some projects of ours all these features are visible in Jenkins, but maven-surefire-plugin is nowhere referenced in pom.xml.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

No, it doesn't need those plugins for this. All that is required is that the results of the unit tests are reported and saved in a certain standard way. See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8790366/jenkins-and-junit).